# Unity3d Physics.Raycast not working ('Physics' does not contain a defenition for 'Raycast')

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, raycasting

So this is my code;

```
void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 100, out hit))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

And  it is *not* working. When I do this it will say;

```
'Physics' does not contain a defenition for 'Raycast'
```

This script is in a *completeley* new project in a *completeley* new script.

Does anybody know the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you show your using directives?

Comment: Did you creat a class named `Physics` ? Could be ambiguous name issue. Give a try using fully qualified name, such as  `if (UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 100, out hit))`

Comment: Can you check in the Package Manager if you maybe excluded the Physics Package?

Comment: Please show us your entire script, this can be an issue where you dont have the correct using directives, an issue with naming conflicts, or a number of other things, a small snippet of code like this does not help us reproduce the problem to help you fix it.  Showing us your entire script not only helps us recreate it, but it also helps us to see if there is any issues with the code you written that could have caused this problem.

Comment: What is the complete error message ? Something like `'Physics' does not contain a defenition for 'Raycast' and no extension method 'Raycast' accepting a x argument of type ... could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` ? I think the current answer posted by Yaroslav is right

Answer (score 1):

I think the constructor is wrong. Try swap "100" and "out hit"

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 100))
```